# SymPy: Why does `solve` sometimes fail, if the equation is in a list?

Tags: python, sympy, solver

According to the [SymPy documentation on `solve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve), the first argument can be:

> - a single Expr or Poly that must be zero,
> - an Equality
> - a Relational expression or boolean
> - iterable of one or more of the above

However, sometimes it does make a difference, if it's `solve(equation, x)` or `solve([equation], x)`. `[equation]` should be an iterable of `equation`, right? And I'm really confused about why it's only sometimes an issue.

**You can see my problem in the following MCVE:**

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols("x y")

def test_sympy_solve(equation):
    print("For given equation", equation, "...")
    print("... solve(equation, x) finds", len(solve(equation, x)), "solutions")
    print("... solve([equation], x) finds", len(solve([equation], x)), "solutions\n")

test_sympy_solve(Eq((x + 1)**2 - 1, y))
test_sympy_solve(Eq((x + 1)**3 - 1, y))
```

**The output is:**

```
For given equation Eq((x + 1)**2 - 1, y) ...
... solve(equation, x) finds 2 solutions
... solve([equation], x) finds 2 solutions

For given equation Eq((x + 1)**3 - 1, y) ...
... solve(equation, x) finds 3 solutions
... solve([equation], x) finds 0 solutions
```

`Eq((x + 1)**2 - 1, y)` gets two solutions both times, `Eq((x + 1)**3 - 1, y)` does not. What's going on here?

Comment: I would consider this to be a bug in SymPy. Can you open an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new)?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug. Submitted an issue to SymPy's issue tracker: [#12326](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12326)

I will keep this answer updated.